# Performance of numerical optimization with triple integral

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, numerics

I'm trying to solve a numerical optimisation that looks something like this:

```
Joint[X_, Y_, Z_] := PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 1/2, 1/2}, {1/2, 1, 1/2}, {1/2, 1/2, 1}}], {X, Y, Z}]

Cond[z_] := ConditionalMultinormalDistribution[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 1/2}, {1/2, 1}}], {z}, {2}]

zstar[y_?NumberQ] := z /. FindRoot[1 - CDF[Cond[z], y] == .3, {z, y - 0.1}]

cap[y1_?NumberQ, y2_?NumberQ] := (1/2)*SurvivalFunction[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, (1/2)], {y1, zstar[y1]}] + (1/2)*SurvivalFunction[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, 1/2], {y2, zstar[y2]}]

q[y_?NumberQ] := NIntegrate[X*Joint[X, Y, Z] , {X, -∞, ∞}, {Y, y, ∞}, {Z, zstar[y], ∞}]

NMaximize[{(1/2)*q[y1] + (1/2)*q[y2], cap[y1, y2] == .1}, {t1, t2}]
```

The definition of `ConditionalMultinormalDistribution` follows [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10220/obtaining-joint-distributions-and-conditional-distributions-using-mathematica)

This numerical optmization problem is computationally very expensive and I would like to improve its performance

Comment: Isn't `cap[Y, Z] == CDF[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, 1/2], {-Y, -Z}]`?  `CDF` is much faster than `NIntegrate` and probably more accurate.

Comment: The constraint `cap[y, 1] == .1` has just one solution, `y -> 0.462678`.  So that will yield the maximum, as well the minimum :).

Answer (score 3):

Note: In the updated question, there is a genuine optimization problem, which is still amenable to the techniques of the original answer.

**Original answer**

I worked on the integral before I realized the optimization problem was trivial.  Yet I thought I might as well share what I got.

It's sometimes hard to figure out when pursuing a symbolic solution will be faster and more productive than pursuing a numerical one.  Numerical solutions are usually fast and approximate with sufficient accuracy, but in this case they are not fast.  Normal distributions have been a subject of intense study, and so there's a chance that *Mathematica* can produce an exact solution.  In this case that turns out to be worth trying.

First, when working with numerics in which you might have to adjust the precision (through [`WorkingPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WorkingPrecision.html), say), it helps to use exact numbers for coefficients and parameters if available (or set the precision high enough with [`SetPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetPrecision.html)).  In this case the distributions to use are

```
BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, 1/2]
MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 1/2, 1/2}, {1/2, 1, 1/2}, {1/2, 1/2, 1}}]
```

Second, `cap[y, z]` is the same as

```
CDF[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, 1/2], -{y, z}]
```

and the built-in function is faster and more accurate.

Third, the triple integral can be solved exactly (with the indefinite limits `y` and `z`).  The first (triple integral) took twice as long as the second (iterated integral):

```
Integrate[X*Joint2[X, Y, Z],
     {Y, y, Infinity}, {Z, z, Infinity}, {X, -Infinity, Infinity}]
Fold[Integrate[#1, #2] &, 
     X * Joint2[X, Y, Z],
     {{X, -Infinity, Infinity}, {Y, y, Infinity}, {Z, z, Infinity}}]
(* (E^(-(y^2/2)) (1 + Erf[(y - 2 z)/Sqrt[6]]) + E^(-(z^2/2)) Erfc[(2 y - z)/Sqrt[6]]) /
    (4 Sqrt[2 Pi]) *)
```

(The timings were `30.770272` and `16.735236` resp.)

---

So a maximization problem can be set up with the integration having having been completed beforehand.  Most likely it would be quick.  I can't really put this to the test on the problem in the OP, since there is only one number in the domain that satisfies the constraint `cap[y, 1] == 0.1`.

---

**Update - Response to the additional problem**

The new `q` can still be done symbolically as above, which will save a lot of time over a triple `NIntegrate`:

```
Fold[Integrate[#1, #2] &, 
     X*Joint2[X, Y, Z],
     {{X, -Infinity, Infinity}, {Y, y, Infinity}, {Z, zstar[y], Infinity}}]
(*(E^(-(y^2/2)) (1+Erf[(y-2 zstar[y])/Sqrt[6]])
     +E^(-(1/2) zstar[y]^2) \ Erfc[(2 y-zstar[y])/Sqrt[6]])/
  (4 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]])*)
```

Note: it helps to do the `X` integral first, probably in this case because it is a definite integral.  This is true even for the triple `Integrate` in the original answer above.

The next most expensive part of the calculation is `FindRoot`.  It can be sped up by about 50%  by using `InverseCDF` instead of `CDF`:

```
z /. FindRoot[InverseCDF[Cond[z], 1 - .3] == y, {z, y - 0.1}]
```

But in this case `FindRoot` can be replaced by `Solve`, since `Cond[z] == NormalDistribution[z/2, Sqrt[3]/2]`.  Both of the following return the same thing (although the first generates an error message about using inverse functions:

```
z /. First@Solve[1 - CDF[Cond[z], y] == .3, z]
z /. First@Solve[InverseCDF[Cond[z], 1 - .3] == y, z] // Simplify
(* -0.908288 + 2. y *)
```

So `zstar` can be defined by a linear equation (and could even be made exact, if desired).

With these changes `NMaximize` takes a little time:

```
q[y_?NumberQ] := (E^(-(y^2/2)) (1 + Erf[(y - 2 zstar[y])/Sqrt[6]]) + 
                  E^(-(1/2) zstar[y]^2) Erfc[(2 y - zstar[y])/Sqrt[6]]) / (4 Sqrt[2 Pi]);
zstar[y_?NumberQ] := Evaluate[z /. First@Solve[InverseCDF[Cond[z], 1 - .3] == y, z]];

NMaximize[{(1/2)*q[y1] + (1/2)*q[y2], cap[y1, y2] == .1}, {y1, y2}] // Timing
(* {2.683494, {0.0970647, {y1 -> 0.816697, y2 -> 0.816683}}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I do realize the constraint makes the problem trivial, but I was just trying to make a small tractable version of my problem to ask the question. Having said that, your point is relevant - and I hadn't realized that using CDFs (actually I need to use `SurvivalFunction` because my actual distributions are not symmetric) significantly improves performance.

Comment: I've edited the question to allow for a non-trivial optimization (and have already included some of your suggestions). Any further advances to solve such a problem would be much appreciated

Comment: @EOO I thought perhaps the constraint wasn't like the real one.  And often the method of solution is dependent on the particular functions involved, so thanks for updating the question.

Comment: @EOO I don't have time to give a good look at your problem right now, but after a quick glance at the new `q`, I could do a quick update.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've changed the question again so that it is framed around the non trivial problem, and not implying directly a solution related to a change in coordinates. I'm not very experienced with the forum, so I hope this structure makes more sense to everyone (I suppose that's why it was put on hold as off topic)

Comment: Your solution is very clear and runs swiftly.

Comment: @EOO  I voted to put the q. on hold because the constraint seemed to me to be a mistake, and it made the integration problem seem moot.  Putting "on hold" is a way to encourage the improvement of questions -- and if a q. isn't improved, it is marked as "[closed](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)".  I suppose this sort of accounting helps others who search the site for answers.  Since the optimization problem was changed, I have voted to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

**Map to spherical coordinates**

The canonical conversion from cartesian to spherical coordinates:

```
map = {a, b, c} -> {r Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ], r Sin[ϕ] Sin[θ], r Cos[θ]};
```

with the scale factor `r^2 Sin[θ]`.

```
q2[y_?NumberQ, z_?NumberQ] :=Module[{map},
    map = {a, b, c} -> {r Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ], r Sin[ϕ] Sin[θ], r Cos[θ]}; 

    NIntegrate[X*Joint2[X, Y, Z] r^2 Sin[θ] /. Thread[map], 
        {X, -∞, ∞}, {Y, y, ∞}, {Z, z, ∞}, 
        Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, 
        WorkingPrecision -> 10]
]
```

Now let's call it:

```
NMaximize[{q2[y, 1], cap[y, 1] == .1}, {y}] // Timing

==> {43.089157, {0., {y -> 0.462727}}}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to compile it but get an error. A couple of questions, just to check I understand what is going on: (1) there is a square bracket missing at the end of the definition of q2 (i.e. at the end of NIntegrate)...right? (2) What is jd?

Comment: sorry for the typos...was on the run and tried to get that thing posted...now everything should be fine...

Comment: If you call the function with any explicit argument, say `q2[1,1]` you get an error message. Do you know what that is? I think that something is going on with it, but `NMaximize` is not picking it up because in this simplified version of the problem there is only one feasible point...